# I can’t get a scroll view to work with storyboards

Tags: objective-c

I can display the `UIScrollView` indicator but I cant physically scroll down to view the hidden content. I’ve used this code in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);

self.scroller.frame = CGRectMake(320,480,320,480);
```

Can anybody out their help me out please?

Comment: You've moved your view offscreen. The top-left corner of your scroll view has been placed just offscreen in an imaginary point just one point right and one point below the edge of the screen. You probably want your frame origin to be `{0,0}` or something onscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  // define the area that is initially visible
  scrollViewCustom.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 354, 500);

  // then define how much a user can scroll it
 [scrollViewCustom setContentSize:CGSizeMake(354, 960)];
```

In addition,clear the background color of scroll view to show the text.

```
 scrollViewCustom.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I have one more question if you don’t mind? I can now scroll down to view the content, however the background image that I have set doesn’t move. So its like the scroll view is on top of the image.